# Grails and jQuery Datepicker messing CSS

Tags: jquery, css, grails, datepicker

I have added a jQuery Datepicker to my Grails application but it seems like it's messing the CSS because the TH and TR of the datepicker get highlighted. But I can't find the exact CSS line that it is causing this problem (see snapshot):

Any ideas?

Thanks!

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1631432/datapiker.jpg

Comment: "datapicker" or "datepicker"?

Comment: it would help to show us some source code or the generated html code

Comment: Exactly aldrin, it would greatly help if he show us some code to that part.